# Statistics question related to the Charleston shooting

Tags: frequency

*Note: This will be a long post, and I apologize for that.*

There's been a lot of parsing of President Obama's words with regards to the "frequency" of shootings in other countries. I contend he's right and haphazardly found two links to support my claim:

- [How school killings in the US stack up against 36 other countries put together (qz.com)](http://qz.com/37015/how-school-killings-in-the-us-stack-up-against-36-other-countries-put-together/)
- [Number of victims of mass shootings in western democratic countries (statista.com)](http://www.statista.com/statistics/248845/number-of-victims-of-mass-shootings-in-western-democratic-countries/)

My friend then responded with the following:

> Wikipedia has a very disorganized page(s) dedicated to rampage killers.  They have their data broken down by things like workplace, familial violence, vehicular manslaughter, political / racial violence, and apparently “standard” rampage killers.
>
> For comparison, lets look at the period since President Obama was inaugurated.  Since then the United states has had 23 rampage killings or on average 3.28 per year.  We are a violent country.  But we are also a large country.
>
> We will start with Norway.  Since 2009 Norway had 1 mass violence incident, and 77 number of victims.  Now since Norway has a population of 5.2 million-ish and we have a population of 316 million-ish that means we are 60 times their size.  They have only had 0.14 rampage killing incidents per year but if we adjust for population, we get a “rampage rate” of 8.69 per year.  Don’t like Norway? Lets look at the Netherlands.  With a population of 17 million-ish, during this same time period they had two rampage killing incidents, or a rate of 0.28 per year, adjusting for population to compare them to the United States that would equate to 5.3 (remember our rate is 3.2 per year).    Let’s look at France, with a population of 66 million-ish, and 4 ghastly incidents over our discussion period they have on average (adjusted for population) 2.73 rampage killing incidents per year.  This is clearly less than the United States.  I would argue it is in the ballpark, but I am probably wrong about that.
>
> Furthermore, let's take the article you posted about the mass shootings since 1966.  If we assume that the United States is about the same size relative to all of the other countries that made the list and we compare the total number of deaths by mass shooting per capita, then here is where we stack up.
>
> ```
> Norway       18.69679
> Finland       4.370678
> New Zealand   3.787921
> Switzerland   2.294606
> Austrailia    1.995309
> Azerbaijan    1.673877
> United States 1
> England       0.676089
> Germany       0.508091
> France        0.417201
> Canada        0.337167
> Brazil        0.111452
> Japan         0.09536
> ```
>
> Wow, get that?  Australia has a population adjusted twice as many mass shooting victims as the United States.

Now, my question is: How can frequency be adjusted for population? I'm not smart enough to see where he's going with the adjustment of a population to quantify a series of events. Something about it just feels off. Is it, or am I just dumb?

Comment: Although the question--which appears at the very end--is on topic here, the vast majority of this text is superfluous and off-topic. If you are seriously interested in this statistical question, then please remove the diatribe.